# navigation hide menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I build a nav menu with jquery, when I clicked on menu icon it will open but when I clicked again on menu icon it will not close

this is html code:

```
<aside class="aside_menu">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
</aside>
```

this is jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".aside_menu .arrow").click(function () {
    var aside_menu = $(this).parent();
    if (aside_menu.offset().right === 0)
        aside_menu.animate({right: "-200px"})
    else
        aside_menu.animate({right: "0px"})
})
```

})

the menu hide in the right side of page and only menu icon show up

sorry for bad language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.offset()` returns an object containing the properties `top` and `left`, so your code will never work because `aside_menu.offset().right` is always undefined. See http://api.jquery.com/offset/

You have to use `aside_menu.offset().left` and then find the proper values to use in the `if` condition according to your page layout.

Comment: is there any replace code for fixing??
my page is rtl and I need to be in right side of page

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a simple way around this problem, but you could try to do some math with `$(document).width()` to get and set the position of your navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Simple things after the biggest resistance line, instead of jQuery, it's better to use JS for such simple things. In addition, animations in JS are clumsy, especially on weaker com-puter and smartphones, which destroys user experience. It's much easier to do it with simple JS and CSS. Probably my code will not help you, but I hope to guide you on the right path.
Ps. Try not to use: "_" (underline) in classes and attributes and id's, because it is in terms of SEO, it is a shot in the knee, a better alternative is: "-" (dash).

```js
var menu = document.querySelector("#menu");
var button = document.querySelector("#button");

function toggleMenu(){
 if(!menu.classList.contains("fade")){
   menu.classList.add("fade");
  }else{
   menu.classList.remove("fade");
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  }
#menu{
  background: pink;
  width: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.34s;
  }
#button{
  height: 30px;
  transition: 0.34s;
  }
.fade{
  width: 0 !important;
  }
.fade *{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<aside id="menu" class="fade">
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">test</a></div>
</aside>
<button id="button">
Button
</button>
```